# dygraphs - chart is overlap fixed positioned div

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlap, dygraphs

I have nav bar with fixed position and static div with dygraph. Nav bar works normally, but when it overlapping dygrahp it becomes transparent and not clickable. 
here is my nav css:

```
nav{
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #dedede;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.055);
    color:#888;
    display:block;
    margin:8px 22px 8px 22px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:
    }
```

div contains graph:

```
#chlone {
    background-color:#fff;
    border:0px solid #dedede;
    border-radius:4px;
    color:#888;
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px 222px 8px 22px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:370px;
    width:620px
    }
```

id graph has no css, here is image
[image: scr]

how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a [`z-index` of 100](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/) (or higher) to the navbar, it seems the graph is on a higher z-index than the navbar and thus overlapping your navbar.

```
nav {
    z-index: 100;
    /*...*/
}
```